# Dependencies causing apt-get to fail to install gcc/g++

Tags: apt, dependencies

I've been attempting to run `apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8` so I can install the `build-essential` package.

I get this error when I try to install gcc/g++:

```
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8 : Depends: binutils (>= 2.23.90.20131017) but 2.23.52.20130913-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't believe that I have broken packages.  I have also tried to install these packages in aptitude without any luck either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

if it doesn't work try:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Go into software sources and make sure you have the universe and multiverse repositories enabled, then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try installing again

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
```

and please list your sources.list file

Comment: sudo apt-get update produced: 

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 981605430AE7FCDA

Comment: sudo apt-get update produced positive results.

sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8 was successful, however running g++ --version returns:

root@vps1484:~# g++ --version
-bash: g++: command not found

Comment: sources.list:

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get install build-essential g++`

Comment: Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up gcc (4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up g++ (4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up build-essential (11.6ubuntu5) ...
root@vps1484:~# g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@vps1484:~# 

Thanks, that worked war1oc!

Comment: you're welcome, if this solved your problem could you please accept the answer? thx :)

Comment: My apologies, it's now accepted.